# Cordova-file-plugin problem about file upload

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I faced this status 500 error while uploading the file to the server.

**Error**
[image]

I use this api to upload the data into the server and this is the data required to post the data. While I test the api using the Postman, it success. But when I run it in my project, it keep show me the error  above.
[image]

This is the data that I passed to api in my project used to post into the server.
[image]

**calling API**
data.image1.file is the File data.
[image]

**orderProofDeliver** it is the post api request, the shorten url is some sort of the api link (http://www.sampleapi.com/api),  and I cant create the code snippet since the code base is in another virtual machine, I unable to copy it out.
[image]

**Error**
this is the formData i passed, i temporary make img1 and img2 passing the same image. Server also response 200 to me, but it cant find the image file

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please show code how you're calling API (POST) call?

Comment: @PankajParkar updated in the post

Comment: Sorry, what is `orderProofDeliver` method implenentation? Please add code snippets, not screenshot. It is easier to suggest modification.

Comment: @PankajParkar I could not update the code snippet here since it in vm

Comment: @PankajParkar i have a question that the file data that append inside the form, the file data is it the form of blob or file data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem to be an issue with Cordova, it is an issue with how you pass data to the API. Basically, you should pass data in using `FormData` api on the browser. And append data into it before sending it inside the body.

**Code**

```
orderProofDeliver(data): Observable<boolean> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('orderId', data.orderId);
    formData.append('img', data.image1.file, data.image1.name);
    formData.append('img2', data.image2.file, data.image2.name);
    return this.http
      .post('destination-url', formData, { headers });
}
```

Comment: it's still doesn;t work,, it returned the same error back.

Comment: i passed the formData to the api bu it still returned the same error, i had updated the code i write and the error.

Comment: @kiku passing header worked for you?

Comment: it actually doesn't related with the header, you can remove it, I encounter the error, because the data.image.file data should be in blob format, and I also missing the filename parameter there.